# I would like to know how I can sort my listview in descending order in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an android application that returns a listview with the data that the user enters, I would like to know how I can sort the listview by FCM order where the largest FCM appears at the top and the smallest at the bottom, now it always lists one below the other, not ordering.

MainActivity.java

```
package br.ldkstudiosart.freqmax;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtNome;
    EditText txtIdade;
    Button btnAdicionarCalcular;
    ListView listAtletas;
    List<Atleta> atletas = new ArrayList<>();
    AtletaAdapter adapter;

    //EditText result;

    View.OnClickListener btClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("EVT", "EVT Clique no botao!");
            processarCliqueAdicionarCalcular(v);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtNome = findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        txtIdade = findViewById(R.id.txtIdade);
        btnAdicionarCalcular = findViewById(R.id.btnAdicionarCalcular);
        btnAdicionarCalcular.setOnClickListener(btClickListener);
        listAtletas = findViewById(R.id.listAtletas);
        adapter = new AtletaAdapter(atletas, getBaseContext());
        listAtletas.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void processarCliqueAdicionarCalcular(View v) {
        Atleta a = new Atleta();
        a.setNome(txtNome.getText().toString());
        //a.setIdade(txtIdade.getText().toString());

        int soma = Integer.valueOf(txtIdade.getText().toString());
        int total = 220 - soma;
        a.setIdade(String.valueOf("FCM: " + total));

        atletas.add(a);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), a.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

AtletaAdapter.java

```
package br.ldkstudiosart.freqmax;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class AtletaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Atleta> atletas;

    AtletaAdapter(List<Atleta> atletas, Context ctx) {
        this.atletas = atletas;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return atletas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return atletas.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atleta_item, null);
        TextView txtNome = v.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeItem);
        TextView txtIdade = v.findViewById(R.id.txtIdadeItem);

        Atleta a = atletas.get(position);
        txtNome.setText(a.getNome());
        txtIdade.setText(a.getIdade());
        return v;
    }
}
```

Atleta.java

```
package br.ldkstudiosart.freqmax;

public class Atleta {
    private String nome;
    private String idade;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(String idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //return "Atleta{" +
        //        "nome='" + nome + '\'' +
        //        ", idade='" + idade + '\'' +
        //        '}';
        return "Nome: " + nome + " Idade: " + idade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort the array in reverse you used to feed into the ListViewAdapter before invoking the setAdapter function of the ListView

Comment: Sorry, could you show me where to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the Comparable<> Interface to Atleta to sort it later with:

```
Collections.sort(-YOUR ARRAYLIST HERE-);
```

Comment: Sorry, could you show me where to do this?